# How to Configure Double Monitor Setup on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, gnome, graphics, multi-monitor, intel

I have a laptop with Debian 10 (Stable) installed. My current setup goes like this:

I have my laptop's embedded screen as one monitor, one external monitor connected via HDMI, and now I have connected a second external monitor (identical with the first one) via [HDMI-USB3 adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T3VF00W) since my laptop doesn't have any other ports and no GPU (only integrated graphics via the Intel CPU chip).

I have successfully installed the [*displaylink-debian* driver](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian), which is a modified version of the official DisplayLink Ubuntu driver, and my new monitor is nowhere to be found.

Here you can see the debug of the driver (when I installed it, the file `20-displaylink.conf` was not generated. I had to put it myself in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and then create the file mentioned with the information printed in the debug (which I found from [here](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/issues/236#issuecomment-471213411)):

> --------------- Linux system info ----------------
>
> Distro: Debian
> Release: buster
> Kernel: 4.19.0-9-amd64
>
> ---------------- DisplayLink info ----------------
>
> Driver version: 1.7.0
> DisplayLink service status: up and running
> EVDI service version: 1.7.0
>
> ------------------ Graphics card -----------------
>
> Vendor: i915
> Subsystem: Processor
> VGA: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
> VGA (3D):
> X11 version: 1.20.4-1
> X11 configs: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
>
> -------------- DisplayLink xorg.conf -------------
>
> File: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
> Contents:
> Section "Device"
> Identifier "DisplayLink"
> Driver "modesetting"
> Option "PageFlip" "false"
> EndSection

When running `xrandr` I get this output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      59.99 +  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x576i      50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Then, when I run `xrandr --listproviders` I get this output:

```
Providers: number : 5
Provider 0: id: 0xe9 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0xc3 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 2: id: 0xa1 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 3: id: 0x7f cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 4: id: 0x41 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

And finally, when I run `lsusb` I get this output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:4301 DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0752 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 400
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5401 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL 8153 USB 3.0 hub with gigabit ethernet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `lspci` I get this output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:17.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series eMMC 4.5 Controller (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

I'm really out of ideas by now. The DisplayLink adapter does show up, but not the monitor. I'm trying to configure it so I have better workflow, and nothing happens. Please let me know if you need any additional info that I missed to provide, and thank you to everyone who gave a glance on my problem.